# Using namespace in django for anchor tag

Tags: python, html, django, url

I am nobish in django ,started django before 3 weeks.I am facing a issue regarding url in anchor tag in html page.I am including all files

## music urls.py

```
from django.conf.urls import url 
from . import views
app_name = 'music'
urlpatterns = [
      url(r'^$', views.index,name='music index'),
      url(r'^albums/$', views.albums,name='albums'),
      url(r'^albums/(?P<album_id>[0-9]+)/details/$',views.album,name='details')
]
```

## main urls.py

```
from django.conf.urls import include,url
from django.contrib import admin
urlpatterns = [
      url(r'^$', include('music.urls')),
      url(r'^music/', include('music.urls')),
      url(r'^admin/', admin.site.urls),
]
```

## music views.py

```
from django.shortcuts import render , get_object_or_404
from .models import Albums,Music
def index(request):
      return render(request,'music/index.html',{})
def albums(request): 
      all_albums = Albums.objects.all()
      return render(request,'music/index.html',{'allalbums' : all_albums})
def album(request,album_id):
      single_album = get_object_or_404(Albums,pk=album_id)
      return render(request,'music/details.html' ,{'album' : single_album})
```

## index.html

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
 <title></title>
</head>
<body>
 <ul>
  <h1>This is music Page</h1>
  {% for album in allalbums %}
   <li><a href="{% url 'music:details' album.id %}">{{ album.album_name}}</a></li>
  {% endfor %} 
 </ul>
 
</body>
</html>
```

## settings.py

```
INSTALLED_APPS = [
'music.apps.MusicConfig',
'django.contrib.admin',
'django.contrib.auth',
'django.contrib.contenttypes',
'django.contrib.sessions',
'django.contrib.messages',
'django.contrib.staticfiles',
]
```

but when I run this code ,I am getting this issue(attaching image) ..and one more thing .. I am using linux, django 1.11.7 version
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After a long research and experiment I found a solution,I am solving the issue

## music urls.py

```
from django.conf.urls import url 
from . import views
# app_name = 'music' <- remove from here
urlpatterns = [
  url(r'^$', views.index,name='music index'),
  url(r'^albums/$', views.albums,name='albums'),
  url(r'^albums/(?P<album_id>[0-9]+)/details/$',views.album,name='details')
]
```

just remove **app_name = 'music'** from urls.py and add **namespace="movies"** or **namespace="music"** in include method ,after the declaration of urls page in root/main urls.py

## root urls.py

```
from django.conf.urls import include,url
from django.contrib import admin
urlpatterns = [
  url(r'^$', include('home.urls')),
  url(r'^movies/', include('movies.urls',namespace="movies")), #added here
  url(r'^music/', include('music.urls',namespace="music")), #added here
  url(r'^admin/', admin.site.urls),
]
```

This will work fine ,and it is only for 1.x version I think,But on 2.x version above(on the question) technique will run perfectly

Answer (score 0):

Change to this:

```
{% for album in allalbums %}
    <li><a href="/music/albums/{{album.id}}/details/">{{ album.album_name}}</a></li>
{% endfor %}
```

Comment: No I don't want a static URL , I need dynamic URL instead of static

Comment: then try this <li><a href="{% url 'music:details' album_id=album.id %}">{{ album.album_name}}</a></li>

Comment: Thank you ,but I am getting the same error 
NoReverseMatch at /music/albums/

Reverse for 'details' with keyword arguments '{'album_id': 1}' not found. 1 pattern(s) tried: ['$albums/(?P<album_id>[0-9]+)/details/$']

Comment: else change url to url(r'^albums/details/(?P<album_id>[0-9]+)/$',views.album,name='details') i think this is better

Comment: While this code snippet may be the solution, including an explanation really helps to improve the quality of your post. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, and those people might not know the reasons for your code suggestion

Comment: While this code snippet may be the solution, [including an explanation](//meta.stackexchange.com/questions/114762/explaining-entirely-‌​code-based-answers) really helps to improve the quality of your post. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, and those people might not know the reasons for your code suggestion.